# Can a component know its child-routes in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```xml
<Main>
  <router-view></router-view>
</Main>
```

```json
[
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Intro,
  },
  {
    path: '/path1',
    component: Main,
    children: [{},{},{}]
  },
  {
    path: '/path2',
    component: Main,
    children: [{},{},{},{},{}]
  }
]
```

I want `Main` to know what child routes are defined for it.

I created a function to crawl around the overall routes object and figure it out,  but its evaluated differently depending on `this.$router.currentRoute` which makes it verbose and terrifying and more complicated the more path options there are in the children. Is there a straightforward way for the parent component to know where it is within the routes and have a list of its children?

IE in the main component how to I tell how many children I have and which of them is currently active?

Answer (score 2):

Will this solve your problem? Here is a [sample codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLrpmR). Everything you need to know and set - route name (even more - you can instead use `meta` or even `path` properties). You can even create recursive function which will search for every route including every `children` array.

Here is a simple function to search for child components knowing parent path name:

```
function recursiveChildrenSearch(routes, name) {
  for (let route of routes) {
    if (route.name === name)
      return route.children;
    else if (route.children.length > 0)
      return recursiveChildrenSearch(route.children, name);
  }
}
```

Can be called like so:

```
recursiveChildrenSearch(router.options.routes, "one")
```

Called on sample routes object:

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/hello',
      name: "main",
      component: A,
      children: [
        {name: 'one', path: '1', component: B, 
          children: [
              {name: 'subone', path: '1.1', component: C}
          ]},
        {name: 'two', path: '2', component: C},
      ],
    },
  ]
```

will return:

```
[Object { name: "subone", path: "1.1", component: {…} }]
```

Comment: This makes sense, although I am looking to do it from within the parent, IE the child route is active but the parent component needs to determine that it is the active parent and then find its children... (one of which could be the active route, unless the active route is a child of those...)

My routes are currently unnamed though, which i think might make this impossible to do

Comment: I think my solution will be to completely rethink the routes and use a prop on the parent-route instead of a route to determine the children.

Comment: Why do you need to know which child is active? Interesting case.

Comment: yeah... we've got a sort of multistep component that's using router to control progress through the steps.. i'm in the process of refactoring it to use just ` {path: ':currentStep'} ` and it's going to be so much nicer

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by looping through the nested routes `this.$router.options.routes` you desire to extract and then push them into an array when the component is `mounted()`

**Note:** I'm using [Vue Class Component library](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) that's why the code looks like this. But the same logic can be applied to Options API and Components API

```
routeName = 'randomName'
pathNames = []


mounted(){
    const routes = this.$router.options.routes

    for (const route of routes) {
        if (route.name === routeName) {
            for (const children of route.children) {
                this.pathNames.push(children.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```